# Creating a rolling window forecast in r

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, forecasting

I need your help understanding rolling window and expanding window forecasting strategy in r . I am using inflation data from Thailand from between January 2003 and December 2014. My problem is as follows:
A) I wish to conduct an out of sample forecast of 4 horizons ahead using An AR(1) model using 50 rolling samples. I wish to set the  length of the rolling forecast window to 36 . The last date in the first estimation period should be December 2008. using the results of the forecast i get a RMSE for each of the four forecasting horizon
B) how one adjust (A) above to have an expanding window strategy

I have tried using greybox package using the following code

ourCall <- "predict(arima(x=data,order=c(1,0,0)),n.ahead=h)"
ourValue <- "pred"
returnedValues2 <- ro(x, h=4, origins=50, call=ourCall, value=ourValue, ci=TRUE, co=TRUE)
plot(returnedValues2)
r=apply(abs(returnedValues2$holdout - returnedValues2$pred),1,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
sqrt(r)
the results were wrong